# The given path's format is not supported.SaveAs

Tags: c#, file, file-upload, file-io, file-import

Following is my code,

```
              string path1 = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Server.MapPath("~/Content/UploadedFolder"), Request.Files
                   ["FileUpload1"].FileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path1))
                System.IO.File.Delete(path1);

               Request.Files["FileUpload1"].SaveAs(path1);
```

I'm getting error saying 'The given path's format is not supported'.What will be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

firstly what u have passed to "FileUpload1"

and y cant u try this

```
 FileUploadPhoto.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/UplodedImages/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadPhoto.FileName));
            ImageUpload.ImageUrl = "~/UplodedImages/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadPhoto.FileName);
```